# Should a use a Knowledge Engine for Expert System in Python?

Tags: python, code-reuse, expert-system, pyke

I need to program an expert system in Python (this is the first time I do both). I have to implement a big flow diagram which depends on progressive user input, i. e. the user provides inputs at many points of the flow diagram. In python, I have seen systems like PyKE for knowledge bases and inference rules; however, I do not understand if a system like that (Prolog-like) will help me with the process of many GUI windows asking many questions to the user or it is better to program it manually.

Should I use a system like PyKE?

Answer (score 4):

If the user's path through the flow diagram is based purely on user input, then I recommend doing it in pure python, unless you have the time and interest to learn how production/rule-based systems work.  PyKE can do what you need but since you are new to python, you will effectively be learning two languages at once: python and the PyKE declarative language.

If your system has lots of other state variables and dependencies that may not be based solely on the user's input, then you may want to use something like PyKE or [PyCLIPS](http://pyclips.sourceforge.net/), which is a python wrapper around the [CLIPS](http://clipsrules.sourceforge.net/) expert system shell.